# What handlers does boost.Asio execute behind the scenes?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

I've got a very simple Boost.Asio case: an `async_read` protected by a `deadline_timer`. I also have a `std::atomic_bool DEBUG[2]`. The `async_read` handler sets `DEBUG[0]`; the `deadline_timer` sets `DEBUG[1]`. This happens unconditionally, even if the error code is `error::operation_aborted`.

Now, when I call `io_service::run_one()` I usually see either one of the `DEBUG` indicators set. However, in at least 10% of the cases, `run_one` returns `1` yet none of the two indicators are set i.e. neither of the two handlers was called. (Also the other side effects of the handler are missing).

Now `run_one` is supposed to return the number of handlers executed, so when it returns 1 it must have executed a handler - but which handler, if not mine?

The reason I ask is because even after a .reset(), the `io_service` object is broken.

Relevant code - rather verbose to make the problem clear:

```
boost::asio::deadline_timer deadline(thread_io_service);
deadline.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(timeoutSeconds));
read_counter += 2; // Initialized to 1 in ctor, so always odd.
// C++11: Cannot capture expressions such as this->read_counter.
unsigned read_counter_copy = read_counter;
read_timeout.store(0, std::memory_order_release); // 0 = no timeout.
deadline.async_wait([&, read_counter_copy](boost::system::error_code const&)
    {
        // read_counter_copy is very intentionally captured by value - this timeout applies only to the next read.
        read_timeout.store(read_counter_copy, std::memory_order_release);
        DEBUG[0] = true;
    }
);

// Start reading "asynchronously", wait for completion or timeout:
std::atomic<boost::system::error_code> ec(boost::asio::error::would_block);
size_t len = 0;

boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer + byteShift), boost::asio::transfer_exactly(nrBytes),
    [&](boost::system::error_code const& err, size_t bytesTransferred)
{
    len = bytesTransferred;
    ec.store(err, std::memory_order_release);
    DEBUG[1] = true;
}
);

// We only have 5 states to deal with
enum { pending, timeout, read, read_then_timeout, timeout_then_read } state = pending;
for (;;)
{
    if      (state == read_then_timeout) assert(false); // unreachable - breaks directly
    else if (state == timeout_then_read) assert(false); // unreachable - breaks directly
    // [pending, read, timeout] i.e. only one handler has run yet.
    thread_io_service.run_one(); // Don't trust this - check the actual handlers and update state accordingly.
    if (state == pending && read_timeout.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == read_counter)
    {
        state = timeout;
        socket.cancel(); // This will cause the read handler to be called with ec=aborted
        continue;
    }
    if (state == read && read_timeout.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == read_counter)
    {
        state = read_then_timeout;
        break; // 
    }
    if (state == pending && ec.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != boost::asio::error::would_block)
    {
        state = read;
        deadline.cancel();
        continue;
    }
    if (state == timeout && ec.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != boost::asio::error::would_block)
    {
        state = timeout_then_read; // Might still be a succesfull read (race condition)
        break;
    }
    // This is the actual problem: neither read nor timeout. 
    // DEBUG == {false,false} when this happens.
    L_NET(warning) << "Boost.Asio spurious return";
}
assert(state == timeout_then_read || state == read_then_timeout);
thread_io_service.reset();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `async_read` to read a TCP stream, that internally sets up an internal hander on `async_read_some`, which when it returns examines the data so far and/or the amount of data received, and either invokes your handler on completion or error, or invokes `async_read_some` again.

I am surprised about a broken io_service, however, but that might depend on where you call reset.  Actually, if you call `reset()` while there are still handlers present and after the captured references within the lambdas go out of scope, then you might invoke UB.

Comment: I'm aware of the lifetime issues, that's why I'm playing those tricks with `read_counter+=2`. If `read_timeout` is set to a value smaller than `read_counter`, it means an old timer expired. The `.reset` was literally the next line, now added to code.

Comment: Might I ask the purpose of all of those atomics?   How many threads have access to the io service?

Comment: While it might have its own threads (depending on platform/functions called), it guarantees that all callbacks that you provide will be executed on the thread that is calling `run` or one of the other methods.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html   As such, all of those atomics are not strictly necessary, since asio will only invoke the lambdas on your thread.  But I was asking primarily to see if you're calling run_one on the same io_service from multiple threads.  That which is legal, but calling reset in that situation would be a problem.

Comment: Each thread now has its own, that's why it's called `thread_io_service`. But I admit that the code originally had a shared `io_service` which made the atomics absolutely necessary. That was even worse; it fairly reliably blocked one thread when the other timed out.

Answer (score 2):

The handler being invoked is an intermediate completion handler created as part of the [`async_read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html) composed operation.  Composed operations are implemented in zero of more terms of another operation, and each of these intermediate operations have completion handlers of their own.  Furthermore, [`run_one()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run_one/overload1.html) does not treat these intermediate completion handlers differently.

In the case where neither the `async_timeout` nor `async_read` completion handlers are invoke, but `run_one()` returns indicating a handler was ran, then the `async_read` operation is being composed of at least two `async_read_some` operations.  This can occur if `async_read()` is initiated when the socket has some data available, but the first read did not satisfy the completion condition.  For example, the socket may have some data, but not all of the desired data (e.g. 0 < `socket.available()` < buffer size).

---

One can enable the [Handler Tracking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/handler_tracking.html) to sometimes get better insight into which handlers are being invoked.  When `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING` is defined, Asio will write handler debugging output to standard error, including handler identifiers.  Here is an example that [demonstrates](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c5fa0d69a171bb9) handler tracking where an `async_read` composed operation will be composed of at least two intermediate operations, and invoking `io_service.run_one()` invokes an intermediate completion handler:

```cpp
#include <functional> // std::bind
#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

const auto noop = std::bind([]{});

int main()
{
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

  // Create all I/O objects.
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 0));
  tcp::socket socket1(io_service);
  tcp::socket socket2(io_service);

  // Connect the sockets.
  socket1.async_connect(acceptor.local_endpoint(), noop);
  acceptor.accept(socket2);
  io_service.run();
  io_service.reset();

  // Write data from socket1 to socket2.
  const std::string data = "example";
  boost::asio::write(socket1, boost::asio::buffer(data));

  // Initiate a composed async_read operation that attempts to
  // read more data than is immediately available.
  assert(socket2.available());  
  std::vector<char> buffer(socket2.available() + 1);
  boost::asio::async_read(socket2, boost::asio::buffer(buffer), noop);

  // Invoke completion handler for intermediate async_read_some
  // operatoin.
  assert(1 == io_service.run_one());

  // Write more data to the socket, allowing the async_read composed
  // operation to complete.
  boost::asio::write(socket1, boost::asio::buffer(data));
  assert(1 == io_service.run());
}
```

When ran, it provides output similar to below:

```
@asio|1477939244.378393|0*1|socket@0x7fff9987bd20.async_connect // 1
@asio|1477939244.378925|>1|ec=system:0                          // 2
@asio|1477939244.379056|<1|                                     // 3
@asio|1477939244.379207|0*2|socket@0x7fff9987bd40.async_receive // 4
@asio|1477939244.379402|>2|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=7      // 5
@asio|1477939244.379572|2*3|socket@0x7fff9987bd40.async_receive // 6
@asio|1477939244.379749|<2|                                     // 7
@asio|1477939244.379874|>3|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=1      // 8
@asio|1477939244.380063|<3|                                     // 9
@asio|1477939244.380249|0|socket@0x7fff9987bd40.close           // 10
@asio|1477939244.380456|0|socket@0x7fff9987bd20.close           // 11
@asio|1477939244.380643|0|socket@0x7fff9987bd00.close           // 12
```

It can be read line-by-line as:

1. From outside a handler (0), invoke `socket1.async_connect()`, creating handler 1
2. Enter handler 1 with success
3. Exit handler 1
4. From outside a handler (0), invoke `socket2.async_receive()`, creating handler 2
5. Enter handler 2 with success and having read `7` bytes
6. From inside of handler 2, invoke `socket2.async_receive()`, creating handler 3.
7. Exit handler 2.
8. Enter handler 3 with success and having read `1` byte
9. Exit handler 3
10. Close `socket2`
11. Close `socket1`
12. Close `acceptor`